# How to specify to Ransack to search in title and body - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ransack

I have a Ransack search. I want to be able to look in the title and in the body in the same time using the logical operator `OR`.

I set the `params[:q][:title_cont]` and `params[:q][:body_cont]` but this search gives me the results only if `title` and `body` contain both the query.

I want to have all the results of the query in title `OR` in the body.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for this [bit in the documentation](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#ransacks-search_form_for-helper-replaces-form_for-for-creating-the-view-search-form):

```
  # Attributes may be chained. Search multiple attributes for one value...
  <%= f.label :name_or_description_or_email_or_articles_title_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :name_or_description_or_email_or_articles_title_cont %>
```

So your view should have a search_field chaining title and body

```
<%= f.search_field :body_or_title_cont %>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. I'll try it and get back to you. Thanks !!